# Как правильно написать свойства wrapper-а?

Tags: css

Вопрос исключительно мучает меня 3 дня и только для профессионалов `CSS` этот вопрос очень важный для понимания как работает верстка так как до этого времени я думал что знал принцип верстки.

Мне надо было написать фон который не меняет свой размер

ТО ЕСТЬ

Начиная с 4К мониторах заканчивая  самых маленьких смартфонах.Конечно же у меня не получилось из за недостатка опыта.Мне дали одну верстку одного программиста. В котором была то что мне надо вот тот код который там был внизу можете запустить.

До этого момента я думал что такое сделать невозможно.Но я очень гулобоко ошибалсья.Запустите код ниже и увеличьте или уменшите экран на любую ширину даже без разницы хоть **+300%** или  **-25%** картинка будет пропорционально менять размер.

Может и кто то это знал но я впервые сталкнулсья с таким.

И когда я вставил этот код в мой шаблон он не сработал хедер сжималсья

И я выяснил что проблема в обертке который я дал всем тегам на своем странице

`wrapper` с одним  свойством у меня было `min-height: calc(100vh - 70px);` чтобы  выровнить футер правильно если кто спросит.

Ну вот теперь все работает.

**ГЛАВНЫЙ ВОПРОС:**

> КАК МНЕ ОБЕРНУТЬ ЭТОТ БЛОК `header` В ОБЕРТКУ ЧТОБЫ `FOOTER` РАБОТАЛ И
>   КАРТИНКА ТАКЖЕ УВЕЛИЧИВАЛОСЬ И УМЕНШАЛОСЬ БЕЗУПРЕЧНО

```css
body,
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Bebas NeueAzeri'
}



header {
    background: url(https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/thumb-1920-82317.jpg) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

```html
<header>
        
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте другой способо выровнять `footer`, через flex. И на моё скромное мнение, если вставляете изображение фоном, то не стоит использовать его в `header`.

А если хотите использовать ваш вариант, то задайте `wrapper` высоту в любых единицах кроме `%`, так как внутрений блок не может применить к себе высоту `100%`, поскольку у родителя задана только минимальная.

```css
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Bebas NeueAzeri'
}

.x-page {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: url(https://images3.alphacoders.com/823/thumb-1920-82317.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

main {
  flex: 1;
}
header,
main,
footer {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="x-page">
  <header>
    HEADER
  </header>
  <main>
    MAIN
  </main>
  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо и кстати это я не засовывал его в header  это было для демонстрации.А у меня футер отдельно от wrapper-а